# Axiom of Choice --Example Problem

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Q: Suppose that for any set $X$ and any function $f:X\rightarrow X$ there exists $g:X\rightarrow X$ such that $fgf=f$. Prove that any set has a choice function.

My attempt:

Let $A=\left \{a,b,c... \right \}\subset X$ be an arbitrary non-empty set.

Choose $f:X\rightarrow X$ defined by

$x\rightarrow x_{0}$ if $x\in A$

$x\rightarrow x_{1}$ if $x\notin A$

$**$ where $x_{0}$ and $x_{1}$ are arbitrary unique elements of $X**$

By hypothesis, a $g$ exists such that $f(g(f(x)))=f(x)$

$\Rightarrow f(g(f(x_{0}))) = f(x_{0})$

$\Rightarrow g(f(x_{0})) \in \left \{x\in X| f(x) = x_{0} \right \}$

By defintion of $f$, $\left \{x\in X| f(x) = x_{0} \right \} = A$

$\therefore$ Since  $g(f(x_{0})) \in A$, $g$ is a choice function that picks an element, $g(f(x_{0}))$, for any set $A$

I feel like this is really close to a correct solution, but the big problem I see with it is that the $**$ step requires that $X$ must have at least two unique elements. My hope is that this can be fixed by just stating that a set with one element $a$ only has one non empty subset $\left \{a \right \}$ and so the choice function can just choose a. Does this fix the proof? Are there any other errors?

Comment: I think you're confusing the term "characteristic function" with "choice function"; although I'm not 100% sure of what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiom of choice does not state "we can choose an element from any non-empty set". This is just existential instantiation.

The axiom of choice *does* state "given *any* set of non-empty set $A$, there is a function $g\colon A\to\bigcup A$, such that $g(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$".

---

In particular, your solution, as written, is wrong. But as you might feel, you are a bit in the right direction. Depending on other equivalences, or the exact formulation of the axiom of choice that you already proved, the proof ranges between "slightly less easy" and "borderline trivial".

What you *should* be doing is starting with a family of sets $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$, and from that engineer a set $X$ and a function $f$, such that the existence of $g$ will guarantee a choice function from the original $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$.

Comment: can I define a choice function $h:I \to \bigcup_{i} A_{i}$ by $i \to g_{i}(f_{i}(x_{0}))$ where g and f are how I defined them above (changing depending on the set)

Comment: Well, you need to *choose* one for each set. That implicitly assumed the axiom of choice already. So no.

Comment: Oh -- I think I was confused by my book's phrasing of the axiom of choice: "Let $A$ be any set. Then there exists a function $f$, defined on the nonempty subsets of $A$ and taking values in $A$, which assigns to every subset one of its members." I didn't recognize that $h$ is essentially just saying given a set, choose an element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of $X$ having at least $2$ element is not a big deal.

However, you seemed to aim to prove the axiom of choice for a *single* set $A$, instead of a given family of nonempty sets. (Note that your definition of $f$ and $g$ depends on $A$.)

So, your proof should rather start with assuming a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of nonempty sets is given, where $I$ is a set, and then provide a choice function $I\to\bigcup_iA_i$.

> **Hint:** Let $X$ be the disjoint union of $A_i$'s, of $I$ and of one more singleton $\{0\}$, and define $f:X\to X$ by sending all elements of $A_i$ to $i$, and all elements of $I$ and $0$ to $0$.

Comment: I'm confused why it matters that the choice function changes depending on the set. Since A was arbitrary and the function is still defined when A has more than 1 element, doesn't that show that a choice function exists for any set? ie, an element can be chosen from any subset of $X$?